# slots failure QWebSocket

Tags: c++, qt, websocket

I'm trying to connect to the webSocket, but as in the example below technically it makes the connection between the signals of the WebSocket, however when it does open I don't get anything in the SLOTS, I left it down as are my .h and .cpp classes

```
#define HTTPHANDLER_H

#include <i9corp/rest/common/HttpRequestHandler.h>
#include <i9corp/rest/common/RequestOptions.h>
#include <i9corp/rest/common/Response.h>
#include <i9corp/rest/common/Request.h>
#include <curl/curl.h>
#include <QtWebSockets/QWebSocket>

namespace i9corp {


class HttpHandler : public Request, public HttpRequestHandler, public QWebSocket
{
public:
     HttpHandler();


    // HttpRequestHandler interface
    Response *request(int method, const char *url, const char *body, RequestOptions *options) override;

    void connect(const char *hostname, int port);

    QWebSocket ws;

public slots:
    void onConnected();
    void onDisconnected();
    void onTextMessageReceived(QString message);

};
}
#endif // HTTPHANDLER_H
```

cpp

```
#include <i9corp/rest/common/Request.h>
using namespace i9corp;
HttpHandler::HttpHandler()
{

}

void HttpHandler::onConnected()
{
    QObject::connect(&ws, &QWebSocket::textMessageReceived,this, &HttpHandler::onTextMessageReceived);
    bool connect = true;
}

void HttpHandler::onDisconnected()
{
    bool connect = false;
}

void HttpHandler::onTextMessageReceived(QString message)
{
    QString aux = message;
}
```

Comment: Are you missing a Q_OBJECT macro in your class definition?

Comment: @Vasilij not because I'm using a library that when I call the conflict Q_OBJECT

Comment: @EliezerHenrique is that if you want to use the Qt slots then you should use the Q_OBJECT macro, why instead of not using Q_OBJECT you ask how to use Q_OBJECT with the library you point out but there are no conflicts?

Comment: @EliezerHenrique, well it was a wild guess anyway. Q_OBJECT is necessary if you want to emit signals from your class. And if you want to add Q_OBJECT you'll have to put public QWebSocket first and then the other classes in your class declaration line. Ok, the problem seems to be somewhere else. I see only one connect in your code, but you speak about slots. onConnected is not connected to any signals, is this ok?